# Flex Regular expression help needed

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, regex

I have created the regexp which allows me to enter == > (digit(0-9)).(digit(0-9) - for 2 decimal)

I am not sure how do I stop, to allow entering "0" more than once.

This is what i have tried:

```
/^[[0-9]]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{0,2}$/
```

But it also allows to enter value like 00000.2 , I wanted to stop user entering any value if its stars with 0. and allow only 0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34n2d)

This allows 0 or a number starting with 1-9 before the dot. The fractional part is completely optional, but when it is existing, it need one or two digits after the dot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it doesn't allows number without decimal points. I mean I need that restriction for 2 decimal but user can enter int as well like 2,3,100 etc.

Comment: That was a mistake in my first expression, I already changed it and updated the Regexr link.